# Checking Reactions/per user, limiting

Tags: discord.js

So, I'm trying to limit the amount of reactions that can be done by each user. I want a user to only be able to react to the message once. If they react more than once, then the reaction is removed and the if statement for reaction is not executed. So,

React once, function executed
React twice, "You can't do that" *remove reaction*

I currently have the reaction collector setup and working, however I need to find out how to get a const to equal the user.id and the amount of reactions that user.id has.

If anyone has any insight, please let me know. Thank you <3

Comment: Are you using a reaction collector or the event?

Comment: Reaction collector

Comment: Take a look at these [options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ReactionCollectorOptions) available for a reaction collector